# Overloading when trying to pass closure as function to JavaDStream

Tags: java, groovy, apache-spark, closures

In my groovy (spock) unit test I build a JavaDStream and then I try to do some stuff with it addressing each of the RDDs in turn. When I try to use the foreachRDD or other similar methods that take a function as an argument by passing in a groovy closure I get overloading issues:

```
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class  someClass] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function]
    [interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2]
    [interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction]
    [interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction2]
```

I tried doing something similar to this:

```
JavaDStream wordStream = buildWordStream(textInputStream)
wordStream.foreachRDD({rdd,time -> println rdd.toString()})
```

Which is what resulted in the above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there are multiple classes (`Function`, `Function2`, `VoidFunction`, and `VoidFunction2`) which Groovy can coerce the closure into based on the method you're calling. It can't decide which to use, so Groovy gives up and asks you to clarify.

```
wordStream.foreachRDD {rdd,time -> println rdd.toString()} as Function2
```

Using the `as` keyword you can tell Groovy which class to coerce the closure into.